# How do I use "eager" lazy loading in chrome with video posters?

Tags: html, html5-video, lazy-loading

Based on my reading of [this article on Google's developers' site](https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading), and my memory of how my site used to work, it seems like lazy loading has become the new default. That's cool! However, I'm running a site that people use to browse a media library, and lazy loading adds a bit of visual jank, so I'd like to disable it in this case.

I understand that I can add `loading="eager"` as an attribute of the `img` tag, however, the way my site works is i display a grid of 60x `video` elements and use the `poster` attribute to display an image until the user `hover`s over and then a super-low-res video preview plays.

`loading="eager"` doesn't seem to work for the posters of `video` elements. What should I do?

Here's my codeblock:

```
<video loading="eager" class="hoverToPlay" muted loop 
 preload="none" src="../media/?clip=1297&q=q" 
 poster="../media/?clip=1297&q=t"></video>
```